# Will available Win10 updates occur when power button is pressed?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, shutdown

In Control Panel > Power Options > System Settings I set the power button to cause a shut down when pressed:

[image]

Will this allow an update to automatically take place when powered on again if an update is ready? I.e., if I have the "Update and restart" option in the Start menu power options. Or, will this cause a shut down without an update process?

Edit:

I have enabled "Install Updates and Shut Down" in the Group Policy Editor (User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Updates > "Do not display 'Install Updates and Shut Down' option in Shut Down Windows dialog box": Disabled).

Does this apply to shutting down via physically pushing the power button as well?

Comment: Updates only get applied during a restart, not a shutdown.

Answer (score 2):

Evidence suggest that it does not. I've seen the guides you apparently followed and while they show how to make sure that option is available in the Shut Down options, they do not indicate this causes the default behavior of the power button to be changed.

Pushing the power button assumes there is some timeliness required of the shutdown process. I would assume, therefore, that pushing the power button will NOT trigger any updates.

All that said, have you actually tried waiting for updates to be ready and then pushing the power button?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sad to hear this. I'm remotely connected to the machine in question, so once I shut down I'll have to wait for someone else to power it on, which could be a while. I'll update here how it goes.

Comment: Remotely connected? You can update and restart too, you know?

Comment: I am not sure I entirely agree with this answer, a shutdown is a shutdown, if you are pushing a hardware button or using the option within the start menu there isn't a huge difference.  I would agree that installing an update, and testing the behavior, is the best way forward.

Comment: @music2myear I can update and restart *now*, but it's an unattended permanent installation. I need a permanent solution.

Comment: Then you need to investigate methods for patching that work within the constraints of the target system. They exist. Also, there are out of band hardware management solutions that could allow you remote access to power the machine back on when necessary, which might mean less effort trying to figure out how patches would work. For a permanent remote installation that's a good feature to have regardless.

Comment: @Ramhound Windows allows shutdowns without updating, and with updating. Not all shutdowns are equal.